# Object Model of a Social Network

Tags: design-patterns, social-networking

Where can i find resources that describes the strategies and patterns of design of social networks object models? For examples, how to implement relationships between users, how to implement the stream of notifications of user actions, how to filter that stream for each user, etc...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This focuses more on the high level view of social networks and internet communities but also from a software point of view, [Clay Shirky's "Here Comes Everybody"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594201536), Jeff Attwood (one of the founders of this site) has [blogged about him](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001122.html) in the past.

Comment: thanks, i just buyed the book, thanks again for recommandation.

Answer (score 2):

You may start with [OpenSocial](http://www.opensocial.org/) to get an idea of a social network API. A general data structure for a social network is a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), where users are nodes and relations are edges.

Comment: Some things in the data model design are simple to understand and to implement (like the graph structure of relationships) but others are harder to me to design (in particular the stream of user actions)